# Find table header that matches a class

Tags: jquery

My table structure is as follows:

```
<table id="report">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="first_name">First Name</th>
            <th class="last_name">Last Name</th>
            <th class="email">Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>Hughes</td>
            <td>larry@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mike</td>
            <td>Tyson</td>
            <td>mike@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to create a selector that references only the header of this table

```
var $table = $('#report th');
```

then inside the click on a radio button, retrieve the index. Here classname is the name of a header class say "first_name"

```
$radio.click(function(){
var th = $table.find("." + classname);
var i = $(th).index();
}
```

But this ain't working. It keeps returning -1 as the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `var th = $table.filter("." + classname);` because your `$table` is not referring the table it is actually referring to the `th` elements in the table. [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) will look for matching descedent elements where as you need to [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the element from the given set of element.

or

```
var $table = $('#report');
var th = $table.find("th." + classname);
```